# CSS: float: right does not expand container

Tags: css

When I expand comment body that is floated to right my container does not expand with it. How can I fix this?

Better explanation: http://jsfiddle.net/5fmpp/

Comment: Parent containers never expand to contain floated elements without additional CSS properties.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` to the container so it can contain the float:

```
.comment
{
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 24px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #777777;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: ...I was using tables for years to avoid that :(

Comment: @seebiscuit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783064/why-does-overflow-hidden-have-the-unexpected-side-effect-of-growing-in-height-t

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ntaXe/) out.

You need to clear the float at the end of the comment box

Comment: Shouldn't it rather be style="clear: both;" instead of clear="both"?

Comment: Using clear as an HTML attribute is deprecated and has been for years. Use the solution proposed by @MazeChaZer instead. See the clear attribute reference [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/clear-html-attribute/)

Answer (score 0):

The modern way to solve this would be to add `display: flow-root;` to the container in order to **establish a new block formatting context**.

`overflow: hidden` also establishes a new block formatting context but with its obvious side effects.