# Why does overflow: hidden have the unexpected side-effect of growing in height to contain floated elements?

Tags: css, css-float, overflow

This question is best explained by [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WuqGM/), with the following HTML:

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner-left"></div>
    <div class="inner-right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.outer {
    width: 100px;
    border: solid 5px #000;
}
.inner-left {
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 50px;
    background: #f00;
}
.inner-right {
    float: right;
    height: 200px;
    width: 50px;
    background: #0f0;
}
```

Basically, I'm wondering why does `overflow: hidden` cause the outer element to grow in height, encompassing the two floated elements?

Comment: I have no idea except that I know that it is the floats that makes it break. You have to clear the floats when you use a wrapper like that. Theres many solutions. Here's one : http://jsfiddle.net/WuqGM/9/

Comment: @Camhänget: Or he can choose not to clear the floats and use `overflow: hidden` as demonstrated. That said, I've edited my answer to include a note about clearfixes - the issue being described here is not a clearfix.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To put it most simply, it is because a block box with an `overflow` that isn't `visible` (the default) creates a new [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting).

Boxes that create new block formatting contexts are defined to [stretch to contain their floats by height](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#root-height) if they themselves do not have a specified height, defaulting to `auto` (the spec calls these boxes *block formatting context roots*):

> #### 10.6.7 'Auto' heights for block formatting context roots
>
> In certain cases (see, e.g., sections 10.6.4 and 10.6.6 above), the height of an element that establishes a block formatting context is computed as follows:
>
> *[...]*
>
> In addition, if the element has any floating descendants whose bottom margin edge is below the element's bottom content edge, then the height is increased to include those edges. Only floats that participate in this block formatting context are taken into account, e.g., floats inside absolutely positioned descendants or other floats are not.

This was not the case in the original CSS2 spec, but was introduced as a change in CSS2.1 in response to a different (and much more pressing) issue. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943503/why-does-css2-1-define-overflow-values-other-than-visible-to-establish-a-new-b/11854515#11854515) offers an explanation for the changes. For this reason, it seems quite apt to call it a side effect, although the changes were very much intentional.

Also note that this is not the same thing as clearing floats (*clearance*). Clearance of floats *only* happens when you use the `clear` property and there are preceding floats to be cleared:

- If you have an element with `clear: both` that's a sibling of the outer element in your example, the floats will be cleared but the outer element will not stretch.
- If you have a similar element (or pseudo-element) as the last child of the outer element instead (making it a following sibling of the *floats*), the outer element will stretch downward in order to contain the bottom edge of that element, and for a zero-height element that essentially means the bottommost edge of the floats. This technique is known as "clearfix" because the element (or pseudo-element) has no other purpose than to force the outer element to contain the floats by way of clearance within it.

Comment: Great explaination. My question: Is there a reason NOT to use `overflow:hidden` , meaning does it have side effects which would lead us into using the clearfix technique over it? Or can either be used safely?

Comment: @TetraDev: Generally there are two reasons 1) exactly what it says on the tin - you *don't* want overflowing content to be clipped (or in the case of overflow: auto, you don't want the container element to generate scrollbars) 2) you want margins of non-floating elements to collapse with the container element (assuming there is nothing else already preventing margins from collapsing). In these situations, it's appropriate to use a clearing element - I recommend looking for a suitable element to apply clear to first, before considering clearfix as a last resort.

Comment: @TetraDev: (Interestingly, some clearfixes like the one by Nicolas Gallagher [contain extras designed to block margin collapse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699262/css-using-displaytable-with-before-pseudo-element/25701312#25701312), rendering #2 somewhat moot.)

Answer (score 2):

The way I explain it to my students is:

You trigger the element containing the floats by telling it, "everything that is to much, don't show", so the element will look for any content that is too much, and it will find some elements that are floating, now it knows that it should contain them.

Comment: You'd need to clarify that this applies only when you have elements that are floating, because anything else will get hidden (that's the point of `overflow: hidden`).

Comment: "will find some elements that are floating" i guess that will do it ? ;-)