# The height of an horizontal ul is set to zero. why?

Tags: css

I want to show the content of my Mega-menu also within the page. I duplicated the CSS styles but it seems that I still miss a rule because the border of the UL with id="wrongBorder_because_of_no_Height" does not show around the whole UL, probably because the UL height is 0

sample page - http://www.teddicom.com/test_07_ul_border_stack_overflow.htm

[compare the border of the floating menu of family 2, and the border of the UL in the page]

- What is setting the height of horizontal ul to zero?
- How can I show the border properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `overflow:hidden` or `overflow:auto` to your class

```
#wrongBorder_because_of_no_Height
{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

The reason why this works is because by setting the overflow property to a value which is not visible - this triggers a `block formatting context`.

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12783114/703717) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.menuInPage ul 
{
height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the height is not fixed, and cannot be calculated easily.

Answer (score 0):

You are floating the li elements left. Parent elements, the ul, are never to expand to contain floated children.

Haven't checked to see if this is what you want but either remove the float or try `overflow:auto`.

Comment: thanks. If I remove the float, i do not get some coloumns. only one coloumn. but it does set the border.