# Overflow: hidden in CSS

Tags: css

Can anyone explain me what this `overflow:hidden` actually does?. I am not able to understand this concept though **reading many CSS tutorials**. I have two floats one on right and other left, why should i apply `overflow:hidden` to my header?.

I am getting confused on this property.

Comment: because of browser's strangeness, the height of the container element will not be right and won't reach till the END of the last floated element, so in order to "trick" the container element to be the right height, to encapsulate all it's floated children, it needs to have `overflow:hidden`

Comment: @vsync: That's not "browser's strangeness". It's completely intentional behavior.

Comment: with my 8 years experience with CSS, I find it very strange, and illogical behaviour.

Comment: @vsync: An element is taken out of normal flow when it's floated. It's completely logical.

Comment: in real life, 99% of the time you'll need to clear it and fix the height of the parent, so in reality it makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`overflow: hidden` on a container simply hides any content that flows outside of the box, as demonstrated beautifully by the following diagram (courtesy of Chris Coyier/CSS-Tricks):

[image: http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/]

You might be using `overflow: hidden` as a kind of clearfix in this case, which is just a way to get a parent container to expand to the height of its floated children (as floated elements are taken out of the normal page flow). The difference between using `overflow: hidden` and `overflow: visible` on containers with floating children can be seen in the [following demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mBeeNO).

Answer (score 1):

If the content of your element is bigger than the container, it will often change the size of the container.  overflow:hidden just tells it to hide whatever content doesn't fit in the container, so the container stays the same size.

Answer (score 1):

There are 5 values that `overflow` can have. They are `visible`, `hidden`, `scroll`, `auto` and `inherit`. By using `overflow:hidden`, you are forcing the content to fit into the specified dimensions without using scrollbars. Thus, only the content that fits within the dimensions will be visible, and the rest is **hidden**.

Perhaps this demo will help you visually see the difference: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow

Sources:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Answer (score 1):

`overflow: hidden` was never intended to directly affect floats — as shown by the other answers here its main purpose is to control content overflow, in other words doing exactly what it says on the tin — but it has an obscure side effect of causing a container to produce its own [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting). When this happens, [the container must expand to contain its floats](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#root-height), even though floats are usually taken out of normal flow. This isn't usually mentioned in CSS tutorials since it's not exactly an intended purpose of the `overflow` property.

Note that this is not the same as clearing floats, since you're modifying the container itself and not introducing some clearing element (as is typical of a clearfix).

See also: [Why does overflow: hidden have the unexpected side-effect of growing in height to contain floated elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783064/why-does-overflow-hidden-have-the-unexpected-side-effect-of-growing-in-height-t/12783114#12783114)