# Wrap floated text at smaller screen widths?

Tags: html, css

Im floating a heading to the left and a div containing a few links to the right. At wide screen widths everything is fine.

At smaller widths the links appear under the heading. Instead I need the heading to wrap.

My content is dynamic, the heading text will vary in length and the number of links with vary also. Therefore I dont believe I can use % widths.

I can alter the HTML however I need to keep the heading above the links in the HTML. This is because for the smallest media query the heading will be above the links.

[image]

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPxbxG

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Title goes here</h1>
  <div class="links">
    <a href="#">Link one</a>
    <a href="#">Link two</a>
  </div>
</div>

.container {
  background: grey;
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
h1 {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}
.links {
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Place the links first in the markup

2) Set `overflow:hidden` (or auto) on the heading instead of `float:left`

[Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/BywQrg) (Resize page to see this work)

The reason why this works is that setting `overflow:hidden` (or auto) establishes a new block formatting context. For more info see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12783114/703717).

```css
.container {
  background: grey;
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
h1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
.links {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="links">
    <a href="#">Link one</a>
    <a href="#">Link two</a>
  </div>
  <h1>Title goes here</h1>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to achieve the same thing while keeping the heading above the links in the HTML's source order? For my smallest media query view id like to keep the heading above the links.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean something like that : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYXBoB ?

I just remove the `float:left;` on the title and put it after the menu in DOM.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to achieve the same thing while keeping the heading above the links in the HTML's source order? For my smallest media query view id like to keep the heading above the links.

Comment: In a différent way, I use `display:table-cell;` for displaying : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JorbmL, but i'm not sure if it what you searched

Answer (score 0):

If CSS3 is an option, then you can use flexbox to acheive this, without having to change the order of the markup.

Just set `display:flex` on the container and `flex:1` on the heading to fill remaining viewport width (not taken by the links)

[Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/qEPqJY)

```css
.container {
  background: grey;
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
}
h1 {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0;
}
.links {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Title goes here</h1>
  <div class="links">
    <a href="#">Link one</a>
    <a href="#">Link two</a>
  </div>
</div>
```