# CSS height:100% not working

Tags: css

I have two divs next to each other.  Usually one will have more content in it than the other.  What I'd like to achieve is that they are visibly the same height.

I've tried to achieve it using display:table-cell; and height:100%; but no luck.

```css
.content {
  background-color: tomato;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: 100%; /* this seems to be being ignored */
}

.table {
  display: table;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*height:100%; if I do this it will also affect height of bigger div */
}

.tr {
  display: table-row;
  vertical-align: inherit;
  height: 100%;
}

.td {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: inherit;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">
      <div class="content">Lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots of content.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="td">
      <div class="content">I wish I was the same height as my fellow div</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hieght 100% in pure css don't think can be done. The simple way would be to assign height value in pixel for the div, both will be same. or use javascript, if content is variable and you want them to be same size

Comment: Can you explain for what reason you need the inner container with class `content`? Both elements with the class `td` already have the same height.

Comment: The content item represents a visual component that I have.  Effectively all I want to achieve is to have two divs next to each other, of the same height.  No need for them to be inside a td - that was just me trying to achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `overflow: auto` to `.content`,
and remove `height: 100%` from `.td`.

Assuming you want `.content`'s text to be vertically centered, you'll need to add an additional element to `.content`.  These styles will work for it:

```
.content > div {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```css
.content {
  background-color: tomato;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content > div {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.table {
  display: table;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.tr {
  display: table-row;
  vertical-align: inherit;
  height: 100%;
}

.td {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: inherit;
  width: 50%;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">
      <div class="content"><div>Lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots of content.</div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="td">
      <div class="content"><div>I wish I was the same height as my fellow div</div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks.

Out of interest - why is overflow: auto needed?  i.e. why does this trick work?

Comment: Don't think I could explain it better than @BoltClock did here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783064/why-does-overflow-hidden-have-the-unexpected-side-effect-of-growing-in-height-t/12783114#12783114

Comment: @F.Müller, you're right.  Your clearfix answer may be a better solution.

Comment: The clearfix solution doesn't work for me.  It just sets the background color on the td, not on the content.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I got you right. But the solutions seem to complicated to me. Actually you can achieve what you want by using this simple markup and CSS. Works in Safari, Chrome, Firefox and should work in IE as well:

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">Really long content</div>
<div class="content">Short content</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/z7e4eopb/)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

```
Removed previous answer as it seem to only work in ff.
```

**Update:**
This snipplet should work for all major browsers: https://jsfiddle.net/4k4653yL/3/

Comment: If at all this would work, it'd have to be .tr { ... }, not tr { ... }.

Comment: I was just editing the answer - I was not finished with it. I want to add js fiddle snipplet as well. But you are right ofcourse.

Comment: I've added the height:100% to .tr in my question as you suggested,  but it unfortunately seems to have no effect?

Comment: It must - I have just coppied your code into jsfiddle and it worked. Can you say me what does not work - maybe provide an image?

Comment: @F.Müller is your jsfiddle finished?  I'm looking at it using Chrome, but the result looks identical to what I have (i.e. the right div is much smaller than the left).

Answer (score 1):

```css
.content {
  background-color: tomato;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: 100%; /* this seems to be being ignored */
}

.table {
  display: table;
  vertical-align: middle;
height:50%;
}

.tr {
  display: table-row;
  vertical-align: inherit;
  height:100%;
}

.td {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: inherit;
  width: 50%;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">
      <div class="content">Lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots of content.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="td">
      <div class="content">I wish I was the same height as my fellow div</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In my browser (Chrome) the right div in your example is now taller than the left?

Comment: Oh, I see - full screen it does for me too.  Problem is, the height: 50% has affected the height of the left div too.  I'm only looking to have the right one match the height of the left.

Comment: @TomG : yeah thanks .. now i check that issue... use the `overflow:auto` on  `.content ` div....  user @Rick Hitchcock  said Correctly :-)

Answer (score 0):

when you give a size in percent the parent needs to have that size set so add

```
height:100%;
```

to body and html

Comment: You mean, add this to my css:

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

Comment: I've just edited my code snipped above.  Didn't seem to help unfortunately.  Did I misunderstand?

Comment: you are forgetting the .table class, that needs 100% too; as I said: the parent of an element that has height in percent needs to have a height set. If that height is also set in percent it goes on until you hit the html element, that youd then have window as parent and window always has a set height

Comment: The problem with setting .table to 100% is that it also affects height of the bigger div.  I just want the smaller div to be the same height as the bigger one.   Is this possible, without affecting the bigger div?