# Why do overflow clear margin of p-tag

Tags: html, css

I just learnt a new "css hack" from my teacher. But he don't know why it works.
I'll explain:

I've on my website a gap (the green line) which I don't want to appear:
[image]

the grey one is the nav element, the black is a div which contains the p-tag "some content" which make this gap because of his margin. (I'll post the code at the end of the question).

My solution would be just delete the margin. But my teacher telled me another way. He added `overflow: hidden;` to the div which contains the p, and poff, the gap is gone.

But how is this possible? Why do overflow affect the margin of an element?

Here's a example code plus a codepen demo:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdQaYv

```css
.container,
.header,
.content{
  margin 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container{
  background; green;
}
.header{
  background: red;
}
.content{
  background: yellow;
}
.overflow{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Contentcontent</p>
  </div>
</div> 
___________________________________________
<br />
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="content overflow">
    <p>Contentcontent</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser always collapses the margins with the nearby margins. When you give an `overflow: hidden`, it calculates all the contents inside it's box model and makes it confine to the content.

**Explanation for BoltClock and anyone else.** *Sorry about my quick dirty handwriting...*

[image]

This is the same case with `float`s too. Floated items do not occupy any space. Have a look here:

```css
div {padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #666;}
```

```html
<div>
  <div style="float: left;"></div>
</div>
```

But the same thing, if the parent has an `overflow: hidden` it doesn't happen:

```css
div {padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #666;}
```

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
  <div style="float: left;"></div>
</div>
```

A whole big article about this concept here: [What You Should Know About Collapsing Margins](https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/). The `overflow` is such a powerful property that it works for everything. But when it comes to `position` you need to use it carefully!

The `position` works like `float`, in the way that both do not take the layout. For eg., see the below snippet:

```css
div {padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #666;}
```

```html
<div>
  <div style="position: absolute;"></div>
</div>
```

Where, if you play with it in the wrong way:

```css
div {padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #666;}
```

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
  <div style="position: absolute;"></div>
</div>
```

The contents above get cut. Hope it is clear.

Comment: What do any of your examples have to do with collapsing margins? You say "This is the same case with floats too", but the example seems to be describing something completely unrelated.

Comment: @BoltClock `overflow: hidden` will make the margins bring in inside the box model...

Comment: @BoltClock Give me a few mins I will upload an illustration for you. I explained in the way he understood.

Comment: @BoltClock Oh yeah, they use. They are using the default margins.

Comment: But yeah, in my example, I have mentioned them for floats. Don't worry, what I have written is for example for floats.

Comment: @BoltClock Please have a look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

`overflow: hidden` causes the container element to establish a [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting), which blocks parent-child margin collapse (though not other forms of margin collapse). This effect is mentioned explicitly in the section on [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins):

> - Margins of elements that establish new block formatting contexts (such as floats and elements with 'overflow' other than 'visible') do not collapse with their in-flow children.

As a result, the margins of the `p` element do not bleed out of the content box of its parent.

You would delete, or zero out, the margins if you absolutely do not want any margins surrounding the `p` element. Blocking margin collapse between the `p` element and its parent *does not* remove the margins from either element.

Comment: Woah this w3c text is deep. Don't understand everything. I think I'll give up trying to understand why overflow do this...

Comment: @Michael Schmidt: That's actually pretty normal - the spec isn't really meant for authors to read. Just understand that overflow has some... [side-effects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783064/why-does-overflow-hidden-have-the-unexpected-side-effect-of-growing-in-height-t) on layout.