# Getting the height of an element which has overflowing margined content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's the case:

```
<style>
  body { 
    margin: 0; 
  }
  p { 
    font-family: arial; 
    font-size: 13px; 
    margin: 13px 0;
  }
</style>

<div id="content">
  <p>The real me lives on the internet!</p>
</div>
<p><code>#content</code>'s height is: <span></span>px.</p>

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var $x = $('#content').outerHeight(true);
  $("span").text($x);
</script>
```

I'm trying to retrieve the total height of a (unmargined) DIV, which have margined content inside it.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Leader/duq58e0v/)

[image: screenshot]

So... yeah... how can I get the `#content`'s total height, INCLUDING the overflowing margins from whatever inside it? (going by the example, the script should be returning 42px instead of 16px)

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `overflow: hidden` for the `<div>` so that the `height` is "calculated" with the contents' margin.

```
#content {overflow: hidden;}
```

You would get the correct value of `41px` now.

**Snippet**

```js
var $x = $('#content').outerHeight(true);
$("span").text($x);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
#content {overflow: hidden;}
p { font-family: arial; font-size: 13px; margin: 13px 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <p>The real me lives on the internet!</p>
</div>
<p><code>#content</code>'s height is: <span></span>px.</p>
```

Comment: Whoa... I really have no clue with the logic behind it... but it works!

Comment: @Leader If you wanna know how it works, please do have a look at this answer of mine. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32142943/462627

Answer (score 0):

Its the `p` element that has the *margins*, not the `#content` element.

Therefore you should use rather use this:

```
var $x = $('#content').find("p").outerHeight(true);
$("span").text($x);
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6pj8rvff/)

Comment: But then $x would return the total height of <p>, right?

Comment: I'm trying to get the `#content`'s height though... imagine if `#content` have multiple P tags inside... thank you for answering, but apparently, simply adding `overflow:hidden`; for the `#content` could do the trick... not sure with the logic around it... but at least it worked :p