# CSS margins and paddings

Tags: html, css

When I try to set `margin-top` to the `#nav` element, why does that property than affects the whole header div?

heres the source:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Improving Great Deal</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      * {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
      #header {
        background: black;
        height: 60px;
        width: 100%;
        clear: left;
      }
      #nav {
        width: 50%;
        height: 40px;
        background: red;
        margin: 5px auto;


      }
      #nav ul {
        list-style: none;


      }
      #nav ul li {
        float: left;

      }
      #nav ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding: 0px 23px;
        line-height: 34px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <div id="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Pocetna</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pitanja</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Informacije</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Zarada</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div> 
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you expecting to see?

Answer (score 1):

The reason being `margin` gets **overlapped** and you need `overflow: hidden;` to show it. See the details below. To include the `margin` of the children, you need to add `overflow: hidden`. The possible explanation for this is as below.

Few possible solutions for this issue include:

```
div { border: 2px solid transparent;
      overflow: hidden;}

div table {display: block;}
```

The browser always collapses the margins with the nearby margins. When you give an `overflow: hidden`, it calculates all the contents inside it's box model and makes it confine to the content.

*Sorry about my quick dirty handwriting...*

[image]

This is the same case with `float`s too. Floated items do not occupy any space. Have a look here:

```css
div {padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #666;}
```

```html
<div>
  <div style="float: left;"></div>
</div>
```

But the same thing, if the parent has an `overflow: hidden` it doesn't happen:

```css
div {padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #666;}
```

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
  <div style="float: left;"></div>
</div>
```

A whole big article about this concept here: [What You Should Know About Collapsing Margins](https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/). The `overflow` is such a powerful property that it works for everything. But when it comes to `position` you need to use it carefully!

The `position` works like `float`, in the way that both do not take the layout. For eg., see the below snippet:

```css
div {padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #666;}
```

```html
<div>
  <div style="position: absolute;"></div>
</div>
```

Where, if you play with it in the wrong way:

```css
div {padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #666;}
```

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
  <div style="position: absolute;"></div>
</div>
```

The contents above get cut. Hope it is clear.

Comment: So did you really read and understand the question, write this long answer and draw an image, took a photo .. just in 3 minutes?! Hm..

Comment: @dfsq I had the answer already in my blog. `:)`

Comment: And you also had it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32142797/why-do-overflow-clear-margin-of-p-tag

Comment: @j08691 Partially yes.

Comment: @dfsq Yes, I read the question. It is about overlapping margins. Am I wrong?

Comment: :) it is, just funny anyway how quick it was

Comment: So it's a duplicate and should be closed as such...no? Especially, as the answer is *exactly the same*!

Comment: @Paulie_D No it isn't a duplicate. [That](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32142797/why-do-overflow-clear-margin-of-p-tag) is a different issue, and this is totally a different question.

Comment: If the answer is the same...it's a dupe in my book.

Comment: Check both @Paulie_D, there's a difference. It is not a dupe for sure. Let me know if it is a dupe.

Comment: Well, the answer is collapsing margins and I'm sure there's another answer (if not your other one) that this could be closed as a dupe of.