# fixed div width changes to 100% unexpectedly

Tags: html, css, css-float

I can't figure out this basic problem. I basically am trying to place the *purple* div next to the *yellow* div. these 2 divs are wrapped in the white div, and the *white* div is wrapped in the *blue* div.

If I float the *yellow* and *purple* divs left, the *white* div changes its fixed width from 960px to 100%, and the *blue* div cannot be seen.

How can this be fixed? I've tried `clear:both` but to no avail.

```css
/* Footer */
#footer-wrap{
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 background:#039;
}
#footer-content-wrap{
 width:960px;
 height:auto;
 background:#EDF5F7;
 margin:0 auto;
}
#footer-left{
 width:500px;
 height:200px;
 background:#CC3;
}
#footer-right{
 width:460px;
 height:200px;
 background:#96F;
}
```

```html
<!-- Footer -->
<div id="footer-wrap">
<div id="footer-content-wrap">

<div id="footer-left"></div>

<div id="footer-right"></div>

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the `overflow: auto;` to both containers and then float your elements, the issue is that when you float the objects the containers will loose the height, you can read more here: [why-does-overflow-hidden-have-the-unexpected-side-effect-of-growing-in-height-t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783064/why-does-overflow-hidden-have-the-unexpected-side-effect-of-growing-in-height-t). Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bb2aseLo/) with your code and the overflow's fixed, I added an extra padding to the containers so you can check the results, if you remove the padding's it will still look like they dissapeared, I also made the white div to red to be more obvious the results.

Answer (score 1):

When you *float* your `footer-left` and `footer-right` divs, the *white* div takes 100% width as its 960px equals the sum of the *footers*.

> If I float the yellow and purple divs left, the white div changes its
>   fixed width from 960px to 100%, and the blue div cannot be seen.

The **blue div is cannot be seen** because you are *not clearing the floats* - clear it with `overflow: hidden` on the `footer-content-wrap`.

See demo below:

```css
/* Footer */

#footer-wrap {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #039;
}
#footer-content-wrap {
  width: 960px;
  height: auto;
  background: #EDF5F7;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#footer-left {
  float: left;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #CC3;
}
#footer-right {
  float: left;
  width: 460px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #96F;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer-wrap">
  <div id="footer-content-wrap">
    <div id="footer-left"></div>
    <div id="footer-right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `float:left` property to your divs.

See this [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zNxOEy).

CSS :

```
#footer-wrap {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background: #039;
}
#footer-content-wrap {
    width: 960px;
    height: auto;
    background: #EDF5F7;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#footer-left {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #CC3;
    float: left;
}
#footer-right {
    width: 460px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #96F;
    float: left;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div id="footer-wrap">
  <div id="footer-content-wrap">    
    <div id="footer-left"></div>    
    <div id="footer-right"></div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I already tried that but it makes the width of the white div 100%, which also means you cannot see the blue div

Comment: You can reduce your nested divs width or enlarge the white div.