# In the code why does removing overflow:hidden; from ul in css style, hides the menu?

Tags: css, overflow

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_navbar

removing overflow:hidden; from ul in css style.
The Menu disappears.
I found the example on w3schools website, when i remove overflow:hidden from style in ul, the Menu is hidden.

Comment: It's still there, inspect the DOM with your favorite browser and check it out.

Comment: yeah it's still there but why removing overflow affecting it?

Comment: If you check the computed stats of the inspector in your browser you can see that the element `overflow: hidden`, in this case the `ul` receives a default height of `46px`, removing `overflow:hidden` leaves the height `0px` as you haven't specified one. As to why `overflow:hidden` does that, see this answer here ► http://stackoverflow.com/a/12783114/448144

Comment: As it seems your question is **why** `overflow:hidden` applies a height, then your question is a duplicate of [**Why does overflow: hidden have the unexpected side-effect of growing in height to contain floated elements?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783064/why-does-overflow-hidden-have-the-unexpected-side-effect-of-growing-in-height-t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your menu didn't disappear, it is still there! You can inspect it like @Fran suggested or simply roll-over your mouse over it's area and you will see it getting highlighted. The behavior you are experiencing is because `overflow: hidden;` causes a new formatting to your block, that means that without it each element will follow it's own formatting and displays with the normal flow. Checkout this [link](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) for more details on block formatting context.

Comment: I'm assuming it is because the question has already been answered several times on SO and could be linked to one of them as a duplicate instead?

Comment: It is up to the person that asks the question to see if it is duplicate or not. We are just trying to help...

Comment: @StefanBob Even you should encourage vote to close for duplication, to ensure a central place for a well written answer to be used. Unless off course the linked duplicate does not answer the question. Furthermore, do **not** encourage "vote fixing" that obvious in public. "Vote Fixing" has resulted in up to 6 month ban from SO.

Comment: I agree with you @Fran,but they should just mark it as duplicate, not down voting a legit answer

Comment: Yea why is the response to downvote our answers if they are correct, not knowing this is such a common question? Makes us feel like we did something wrong. Wouldn't be a need to "vote fix" lol (give me a break)

Answer (score 0):

`ul` is a block level element. When the `li` are floated they take up no space and therefore the height of the `ul` is reduced to 0.

Now declaring overflow (anything but visible) on the `ul` creates a new block formatting context, which makes the `ul` contain its children and not be 0px height anymore.