# How does overflow:hidden stops the parent from collapsing on floating it's children?

Tags: html, css, css-float, overflow

The code below stops the `clearfix` parent element from collapsing when both of it's children are floated.

Can anyone tell me how / why it works?

```css
.clearfix {
  overflow: hidden; /* can also be "auto" */
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
  <div style="float: left;">Div 1</div>
  <div style="float: left;">Div 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/#article-header-id-2

Comment: @TemaniAfif It says "the parent will expand to contain the floats, effectively clearing it for succeeding elements."

But float removes the elements from the normal HTML flow, so the question was, why parent expands to contain the elements?

Comment: you have to read carefully :) check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783064/why-does-overflow-hidden-have-the-unexpected-side-effect-of-growing-in-height-t/12783114#12783114

Comment: i added many links with very detailed answer that also links to the specification, so take time to read them and also their link and you will understand ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks!